# Disable selected option of one dropdown for all other dropdown

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have multiple dropdowns which contain the same array values, I want to disable option which is selected in one dropdown for other dropdowns so how can I achieve that?

```
 <div>
    <div>
      <label >Name</label>
    </div>
    <div >
      <select >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of Demo">{{type}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div>
    <div>
      <label >Number</label>
    </div>
    <div >
      <select >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of Demo">{{type}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

.ts File
Demo = ['One', 'Two','Three']
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. You can solve the problem by removing the selected option from other arrays.

Comment: I have tried nothing because I have no idea how to do that.I am a newbie to angular7

Comment: can you please share your html and ts here. so that we can help you better

Comment: How many Select would be there? Max 2?

Comment: no there are 20 dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label >Name</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValues[0]">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let type of Demo" [ngValue]="type" [disabled]="isDisabled(type)">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <label >Number</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValues[1]">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let type of Demo" [ngValue]="type" [disabled]="isDisabled(type)">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
Demo = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
  selectedValues = [];
  isDisabled(value) {
    return this.selectedValues.includes(value);
  }
```

If you have 20 dropdown, put the html code to *ngFor and bind the label, value to its.

Comment: there are 20 dropdowns